# What were the main clans of the Sengoku period?

Tags: japan, sengoku

I'm looking for some kind of **authoritative** list of the main clans operating during the Sengoku period, if possible with each clan's kamon but most importantly which geographical areas they controlled.

I know I'm asking for quite a lot but I have difficulty finding anything I can deem reliable.

Comment: What sources did you look at and why were they lacking?

Comment: Top 2. ¶ Wikipedia: Best source i've found so far, but I'm keeping it as my last resort because the narrative nature of wikipedia would force me to spend hours compiling the list form bits and pieces of info here and there. I'm sure someone has done this already, that's what I'm looking for. ¶ Samurai-archives.com: Had decent information, I built most my original list from this information but then started seeing contradictions /w some random source articles which lead me to conclude that I needed a more authoritative resource.

Comment: What is missing e.g. in the relevant wikipedia page? It is a long period, which can cause differences between lists.

Answer (score 3):

See this link

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People_of_the_Sengoku_period_in_popular_culture

Comment: "authoritative" is bolded, maybe he doesn't consider Wikipedia as such?

Comment: Also, adding just a link to a wikipedia article doesn't constitute an answer.  See the FAQ - http://history.stackexchange.com/faq and this thread - http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/4/should-we-allow-wikipedia-to-be-referenced-as-an-academic-source-in-answers

Comment: @Lohoris I do consider SOME wikipedia articles to be authoritative but that link doesn't even come close to answering this question.